# How we get Untraslated model in Foreign key relation in Django_cms(hvad)

Tags: python, django, models, multilingual, django-hvad

I am using hvad for multilingual model in django-cms in my project two application Degree,Domain
in my setting.py two languages are used

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
]
```

Degree model.py is in multilingual structure:

```
class Degree(TranslatableModel):

translations = TranslatedFields(

    degree_nm = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Degree Name')),
    des = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Description')),
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Title')),
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Slug')),
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True),
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True),
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, editable=False),   
)
```

Now in Domain Application make foreign key relationship in django-cms
Domain 's models.py is in that i am not use TranslatableModel, use normal model

```
class Domain(TranslatableModel):    

translations = TranslatedFields(
degree = models.ForeignKey('degree.Degree')
domain_nm = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name ='Domain Name')
des = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Description')
title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name='Title')
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, verbose_name='Slug')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
)
```

So when I add record in domain in django-cms, it only shows the current language entry. I wish to get the record in both English and French at same time.

Thanks in advance!!!